# Composing a Java Function and Consumer

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, function-composition

What is the best way to functionally compose a java `Function` and a `Consumer`?
For example given some `Function<Object, String> f` and some `Consumer<String> c` then doing `f.andThen(c)` would feel natural, however that is not how the interfaces work.

The two options I see are either replace `Consumer<String> c` with `Function<String, Void> c` or change `Consumer<String> c` to `BiConsumer<Function<Object, String>, String> c` and do

```
accept(Function<Object, String> f, Object o) {
    String thing = f.apply(o);
    //do something with thing
}
```

Is one of these better than the other? Is there a better way?

Comment: Can you provide a use-case for this?

Comment: I'd write my own `Consumer` class for this. It would take some 10 lines of code.

Comment: @Tunaki a simple use case would be if we had an object we wanted to serialize as a string different ways (the function) and then we wanted to output it somewhere like to the database or to the terminal (the consumer)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik what would that look like?

Comment: Well, I was wrong---Misha showed how it could be done in a one-liner :) My imagined class was a manual implementation of this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
Consumer<Object> composed = o -> c.accept(f.apply(o));
```

If you find yourself faced with this problem a lot, you can make a static method to do this (but is it *really* worth it?):

```
static<T,R> Consumer<T> applyAndAccept(Function<? super T,? extends R> f, Consumer<R> c){
    return t -> c.accept(f.apply(t));
}
```

Comment: Sometimes it worth: you can use two cool method references instead of single boring lambda. If your method-references are instance bound and instance is stored in non-final variable, then lambda version may look really clumsy. In this context your proposed static method is even better than non-existing default method `andThen(Consumer)`, because the method reference type will be inferred automatically.

Comment: @TagirValeev I agree, ability to use method references is a big plus.  I just don't run into `Function`-`Consumer` situation often enough, but maybe others do.  What I do bump into all the time is the need to compose `Function` and `Predicate`.

Comment: @Misha why don't you run into this situation often enough? Don't you often do: `arr.forEach(func1.andThen(func2).andThen(func3).andThen(consumer))`?

Answer (score 3):

You can make a copy of the java.util.function.Function interface in your own code. Call it ConsumableFunction and change all default method parameter types and return values from Function to ConsumableFunction. Then add the following default function:

```
default Consumer<T> atLast(Consumer<R> consumer) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(consumer);
    return (T t) -> consumer.accept(apply(t));
}
```

Now let all your Function implmementations implement ConsumableFunction instead. Then you can write code like this:

```
Consumer<A> consumerForA = functionFromAToB
    .andThen(functionFromBToC)
    .andThen(functionFromCToD)
    .atLast(consumerForD);
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this accomplished using `map` and `forEach`?

```
public void test() {
    Function<Object, String> f = (Object t) -> t.toString();
    Consumer<String> c = (String t) -> {
        System.out.println(t);
    };
    List<Object> data = new ArrayList<>();
    data.stream().map(f).forEach(c);
}
```

Comment: You essentially don't execute anything, because your stream missing the terminal operation. Also stream processing is just an example of using `Consumer`. They can be useful in other places as well.

Comment: @TagirValeev - Interesting - adding `.toArray()` seems to fix that though.

Comment: This is an abuse of `peek`.  Just do `.map(f).forEach(c)`  or `.map(f).forEachOrdered(c)` if `c` is not thread-safe.