# How to compose Function<T, R> and Consumer<R> in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, functional-java

Why can't we compose Function and Consumer just like we compose functions?

```
Function<Integer, String> a = Object::toString;
Consumer<String> b = x -> System.out.println(x);
Consumer<Integer> composed = a.andThen(b);
```

This seems like an obvious improvisation to the existing Function interface. Is there any reason why this capability was avoided in Java 8?

Also, is it a common practice to use an extended implementation of Function as follows?

```
interface FunctionImproved<T, R> extends Function<T, R> {
    default Consumer<T> andThen(Consumer<R> consumer) {
        return x -> consumer.accept(apply(x));
    }
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/32646249/3920048

Answer (score 2):

The `andThen` method on a `Function<A0, A1>` instance expects a `Function<A1, A2>`, not a `Consumer<A1>`:

```
a.andThen(string -> {
    b.accept(string);
    return string;
});
```

It has a side-effect since our "consumer" (actually, it's a `Function<A1, A1>`) will be returning an ignored value from the previous `Function<Integer, String> a` function. It's not what we want.

---

There is a different way to compose a `Function<A0, A1>` and a `Consumer<A1>`:

```
Consumer<Integer> c = i -> b.accept(a.apply(i));
```

which can be generalised to a utility method:

```
<A0, A1> Consumer<A0> functionAndThenConsumer(Function<A0, A1> f, Consumer<A1> c) {
    return i -> c.accept(f.apply(i));
}
```

---

> Is it a common practice to use an extended implementation of `Function`?

There are two options:

1. Having static methods that do some conversions between functional interfaces (like I did).
2. Extending these standard functional interfaces with default methods (like you did). Just choose a right meaningful name, not like `FunctionImproved`.

Comment: for the utility method ideally you'd want `Function<? super A0, ? extends A1> f, Consumer<A1> c` as the parameters rather than `Function<A0, A1> f, Consumer<A1> c`.

Comment: @Aominè, we can do this only for `A0`, because of `Consumer<A1>`, right?

Comment: nope, we can do it for both as `? extends A1` would definitely satisfy `c.accept(...)`.

Comment: `? extends A1` is different for `Consumer` and `Function`, isn't it?

Comment: Hmm, `i -> b.accept(a.apply(i))` or `functionAndThenConsumer(a, b)`… Regarding option 2, I don’t see how extending the functional interface helps when you already have two instances of the standard interfaces. And when you don’t have existing instances, there’s even less sense in creating a `FunctionImproved` instance just to call a combining method afterwards, when you can use a readable lambda in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

`Function`s and `Consumer`s serve two different masters (in a sense).

- A function accepts one (or two in the case of `BiFunction`) types and produces a third type, which may be either the first or second type.
- A consumer accepts one (or two in the case of `BiConsumer`) types, and produces *no* output.

In *both* cases, there should be a **discrete** and **single** operation being done, which would make it easier to reason about the operation's thread safety.

It *looks* like you're trying to do a simple mapping of one type to another (String to Integer), then call an operation on it.  If your elements were in a `Stream`, this could be written as:

```
elements.map(Objects::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
```

...and if it were in a collection or `IntStream`, you could use this instead:

```
elements.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Ultimately what you're attempting may be a solution in search of a problem.  Once you're clearer as to the role that functions and consumers actually play, attempts at compositions like the above become less necessary.

Answer (score 1):

> Why can't we compose Function and Consumer just like we compose functions?

It's all about Java's type system. The `Function.andThen` method accepts an argument of type `Function` (which is not of type `Consumer`). There's no relation between a `Consumer` and a `Function` in Java, i.e. one doesn't extend the other one, so you can't pass a `Consumer` to `Function`'s `andThen` method.

There are workarounds available, though. One is with a default method, as you showed, while another approach would be to use a static method, as shown in [Andrew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47520213/1876620).

Here's another way, using a higher-order function:

```
BiFunction<Function<T, R>, Consumer<R>, Consumer<T>> composer =
    (function, consumer) -> t -> consumer.accept(function.apply(t));
```

You can use it this way:

```
Consumer<Integer> composed = composer.apply(Integer::toString, System.out::println);
```

Answer (score -1):

There's no reason, why this composition should not exist as part of the Function API. The designers of Java 8 simply did not foresee all possible combinations and use cases: that's why Java 9 added some more convenience methods and probably we'll see more in coming releases.

Regarding the "improved" function, I would not dare to create a new interface just for that, especially considering the choice of the interface name. The suffix "Improved", just like all the "Utils", "Helpers" etc, does not possess self-explaining semantics and should be avoided. Better solution is to create a functional namespace like this:

```
final class Compositions {
     private Compositions() {}
     public static <T,R> Function<Consumer<R>, Consumer<T>> to(Function<T,R> f) { 
          return consumer -> (value -> consumer.accept(f.apply(value));
     } 
}

import static Compositions.*;
Function<Integer,String> stringValue = Integer::toString;
Consumer<Integer> printInt = to(stringValue).apply(System.out::println);
printInt.accept(1);
```