# Composing a Java BiFunction and Consumer

Tags: lambda, java-8, functional-programming, function-composition

Similar to this question [Composing a Java Function and Consumer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32646249/composing-a-java-function-and-consumer). What is the best way to functionally compose a java BiFunction and a Consumer? For example given some BiFunction<String, String,String> f and some Consumer c then doing f.andThen(c) ?

```
BiFunction<String, String, String> a = (a,b)->{return a+b;}
Consumer<String> b = x -> System.out.println(x);
Consumer<String> composed = a.andThen(b);
```

Comment: Seems like the solution would be the same as in the Q&A you linked, just with `BiFunction` instead of `Function` (maybe also with a `BiConsumer`?). Is there a specific problem you're having with adapting the code?

Comment: I want to write a Generic Methods that implements the combined use of BiFuncton and Consumer

Comment: You can not compose a `BiFunction` and `Consumer` to a `Consumer`. The former expects *two* arguments, hence, the result has to be a `BiConsumer`. Besides that, if you want “to write a Generic Method”, then do it. As Slaw said, you can use the Q&A you already linked and adapt it. Feel free to ask questions about your actual attempt, if you struggle.

Answer (score 0):

You can only compose `BiFunction`s with `Function`s. Then you may create a `Function` returning `Void` and get with a composition a `BiFunction` in return:

```
BiFunction<String, String, String> a = (x,y)->{return x+y;};
Function<String,Void> b = x -> { System.out.println(x); return null; };
BiFunction<String,String,Void> f = a.andThen(b);
f.apply("foo","bar");
```

which will give you:

```
foobar
```

`Function<...,Void>` are slightly tricky as Java generics can only be instanciated with classes, not with primitive types as `void` is. You then need to return a `Void` object reference, but this type cannot be instanciated and the only value you can use is `null`.

At the end if you need a `BiConsumer` you can build it like this:

```
BiConsumer<String,String> c = (x,y) -> f.apply(x,y);
```